# UI Router Regex Params

Tags: angularjs

I have a route that should accept this kind of param:

> FQvLiOUp8szeVbUbztK/wzYW6ipnomDfIh2RbPv4FrXDO3In4gRFDg==

This is my routing code:

```
 $stateProvider
        .state('activation', {
            url: '/activate/{activationCode}',
            templateUrl: './app/gol88/security/page/activation.page.html',
            controller: 'ActivationController as activationCtrl'
        })
    ;
```

But this doesnt accept the param which is my activation code.

How can i do that?

Thanks.

NOTE that there is "/" character on it. I tried other activation code and it worked.

Comment: Whats error giving in console try using `url: '/activate/:activationCode',`

Comment: it doesnt give any error, it just doesnt go to the route.

Comment: have you a tried give solution

Answer (score 0):

Basic Parameters

Often, URLs have dynamic parts to them which are called parameters. There are several options for specifying parameters. A basic parameter looks like this:

```
$stateProvider
.state('contacts.detail', {
    url: "/contacts/:contactId",
    templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html',
    controller: function ($stateParams) {
        // If we got here from a url of /contacts/42
        expect($stateParams).toBe({contactId: "42"});
    }
});
```

Alternatively you can also use curly brackets:

```
// identical to previous example
url: "/contacts/{contactId}"
```

Comment: what i need is the regex to accept my activation code.

Comment: you can use npm module crypto to creating coded activation code and saving and checking value,
for creating regex you can visit http://regexr.com/,
helpful?